# Getting phpStorm Live Templates to fill out last declared variable

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have recently switched from Netbeans to PhpStorm and I am missing this feature.

Is there a way to get PhPStorm to automatically fill out the previously declared variable in a Live Template?

I would like to be able to place the cursor after a line like this

```
$stuff = $this->getStuff();
```

And have a template that automatically knows that I would like to use the $stuff variable like so

```
if (!empty($VariableBestGuess$))
{
    print_r($VariableBestGuess$);
}
```

So it automatically fills out this code

```
if (!empty($stuff))
{
    print_r($stuff);
}
```

I have tried clicking "Edit Variable" on the $Variable$ and set the Expression to "phpSuggestVariableName()" but it does not seem to do anything.

The documentation says "**js**SuggestVariableName" which I am not sure if is intended.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/live-template-variables.html

---

UPDATE: I have submitted this as a feature request: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist/show?pr=&wid=526

Comment: Any news on this request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such function. You can use `complete()` to have PHPStorm invoke the completion to choose from when applying the template, or use `clipboard()` and make sure to copy your variable name prior to expanding the template

Comment: I just have the same question again. After almost 3 years, did PHPStorm implement any functionalities for the same question above. I was able to use it in netbeans snippets, there I was able to use this to receive the previous variable declared.
> dump(${VARIABLE variableFromPreviousAssignment default="$variable"});
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Another 4 years, still not implemented in PhpStorm! Almost went back to Netbeans because of this, almost…

Answer (score 1):

You can create Macros for this task.

1. Select variable
2. Start macro recording
3. Ctrl+C (copy the name of the variable)
4. Go to the end of line and hit enter
5. Type if(!empty(
6. Paste variable ad type other part of your code
7. Stop macro recording
8. Assign key to the macro

Then you can simple select variable and hit hotkey.
[image]